# Elastic search not giving correct results when performing date range query

Tags: elasticsearch, range

I am trying to filter the results from elastic search based on the dates falling between start date and end date.Elastic search version is 1.7.6.

It is giving completely wrong results.
I am using marvel for querying the index.

The schema is

```
"starting_on": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "dateOptionalTime"
          }
My query is below:--

          GET XX/XX/_search
          {
             "_source": [
              "arrivals.starting_on",
                 "arrivals.ending_on"
                ],
              "query": {
              "filtered": {
             "filter": {
                "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {

                "starting_on": {
                  "gte" :   "2017-10-14",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime",


                },
                 "ending_on": {
                  "lte" :    "2017-10-17",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime",

                }
              }

            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Given what you have in `_source`, are you sure that in your range query `starting_on` should not be `arrivals.starting_on` (same for `ending_on`) ?

Comment: query is not giving any hits when I am doing arrivals.starting_on or arrivals.ending_on

Answer (score 0):

Your `range` query is wrong, you cannot have two fields in it, you need to have two `range` queries instead, like this:

```
GET XX/XX/_search
{
  "_source": [
    "arrivals.starting_on",
    "arrivals.ending_on"
  ],
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "arrivals.starting_on": {
                  "gte": "2017-10-14",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "arrivals.ending_on": {
                  "lte": "2017-10-17",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @ShahrukhAnwar care to explain?

Comment: I am still finding the solutions how to get precise results on date ranges.

Comment: The most important thing is when you are dealing with `date`, that when you are indexing your data into elasticsearch you have to make sure that your `date` related columns must be taken as `date` not as `string`.